# Does TCP stack ever send unsolicited RST on existing connection

Tags: linux, sockets, tcp

We have a linux system where data is being streamed from the server side of a TCP connection to a client side. [edit: both sides are using the sockets API]

At a point in time while this is happening our local TCP pcaps show a RST being sent from the client to the server, and client side logs show that reads are returning 0 bytes.

Is it *possible* for the RST to be sent unsolicited from the stack and then have subsequent client reads return 0 bytes?

Code is third party proprietary, so I can't share samples or snoops. I am asking this question in an effort to understand if TCP stack sending an unsolicited RST is a possible explanation for the above detailed behavior, and if so what would have to take place to trigger this.

Comment: Does this happens in the middle of the streaming between the client and the server? Or after a server has finished sending data and is idle?

Comment: @PauloBu: this happens during the streaming

Comment: What the platform is? Might it be buggy? The connection is being lost perhaps?

Comment: CentOS release 5.8 (Final)

Comment: Yes, it is possible using `raw sockets`. Might be a portscan

Comment: It is highly unlikely that it's caused by the TCP stack, whereas it is well possible to be a bug in the client on application level.

Comment: Which side is the proprietary code on ? And are there any FIN from either side before this happens on the connection (the FIN might not neccesarily be nearby in time, so look throught the connection from the start)

Comment: @hek2mgl: neither side uses raw sockets, but thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: @daniel: we are considering the possibility of an application level bug, but wanted to be able to rule out other possibilities as well.

Comment: @nos: Good possibility, but this isn't the case. I used a wireshark filter to look for FIN or RESET on this connection and only found the RESET.

Comment: @nos: proprietary code on both sides.

Answer (score 2):

This could also be a forged RST. Forged RSTs can be sent by a third party which wants to terminate your connection. This has been done in the past in industry-grade size. Read more here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TCP_reset_attack#Forging_TCP_resets

To rule this out, you need to sniff the traffic at the client computer and see if it actually sends the RST, or if the RST is only received by the server side.

Comment: we have local pcaps on both sides, the RST shows in both as being sent from client to server.

Comment: Then disregard my answer above. It's not a forged RST.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible for the application to terminate the connection with an RST instead of a FIN, by fiddling with the `SO_LINGER` option. A well-written application should not do this.